# What fluid is generally used for laboratory testing of hydraulics?

Tags: civil-engineering

Which liquid is generally used or is it better to carry out hydraulic laboratory tests?

Answer (score 2):

It is always best to use the hydraulic fluid recommended by the manufacturer of the cylinder, pump, valve, regulator or whatever.